# Metering Camera - Android

Tags: android, camera

I am using the function Camera.Area:

```
if (params.getMaxNumMeteringAreas() > 0){ // check that metering areas are supported
List<Camera.Area> meteringAreas = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();

Rect areaRect1 = new Rect(-100, -100, 100, 100);    // specify an area in center of image
meteringAreas.add(new Camera.Area(areaRect1, 600)); // set weight to 60%
Rect areaRect2 = new Rect(800, -1000, 1000, -800);  // specify an area in upper right of image
meteringAreas.add(new Camera.Area(areaRect2, 400)); // set weight to 40%
params.setMeteringAreas(meteringAreas);
}
```

but, when i try running, the program give me Exceptions. `NoSuchErrorMethodError in params.getMaxNumMeteringAreas() and NoClassDefFoundError in  meteringAreas.add(new Camera.Area(areaRect1, 600));.`

Does anyone know how sloved the error ?

Answer (score 2):

The Android documentation for the above API states that it is available from API 14 onwards, which means it is available only on ICS and above devices.

You might be compiling using the latest Android SDK which includes the ICS packae too, but the device might running any older version of Android. So first check if the Android version on the device you are running is ICS.